# Compatibility of connect USB Type-C device to Thunderbolt 1 MacBook Pro?

Tags: usb, ssd, macbook, usb-3, thunderbolt

Says I have a MacBook Pro (mid-2012 A1278 with i7 3520M), with only Thunderbolt 1 slot (10Gbps)

Now I have an External SSD hard drive with USB Type-C peripheral. In order to connect them, I have to purchase two connectors. [link1](http://www.apple.com/uk/shop/product/MMEL2ZM/A/thunderbolt-3-usb-c-to-thunderbolt-2-adapter) The Thunderbolt cable and an adapter [link2](http://www.apple.com/uk/shop/product/MD862ZM/A/apple-thunderbolt-cable-05m-white) for Thunderbolt to USB type-C.
Now assume the hard drive speed is NOT the bottleneck, will I get them working together and get a 10Gbps connection for example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The adapter in Link1 is designed to work on HOST side, converting Thunderbolt3- Type-C to Thunderbolt and Thunderbolt2 devices. The adapter [does not support](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT207266) any purely-USB3 devices. Type-C connector does not necessarily mean USB 3.1 functionality.

More, you seem to plan to use the adapter on device side, which won't work at all.

In short, sorry, you will have no functionality from this setup at all.

Comment: Thank! Saved me a lot. So what I need may be a power side thunderbolt 2 adaptor with type c output which is hard to find in the market.

Comment: @user958916, I think there should be some Apple devices that adapt Tunderbolt1 to a regular USB 3.0 hub, not necessary to Type-C USB, like a dock or something. Then you can use a legacy Type-A to Type-C cable assembly to connect your HDD. You might get 5Gbps from this. This Belkin device connects to Thunderbolt2, but I don't know if it is backward compatible with the initial Thunderbolt, http://www.belkin.com/us/F4U085-Belkin/p/P-F4U085/

Comment: @user958916, see what I found for you: https://www.amazon.com/Kanex-Thunderbolt-eSATA-plus-Adapter/dp/B00LOLBBQQ  It appears that Thunderbolt is completely incompatible with USB, so no simple USB hub is possible. It looks like the Kanex device uses some sophisticated bridges to interface with eSATA and USB3.

Comment: Thanks. @Ali Chen, Unfortunately, the SSD have the type C port with a 10GB connection (advertise removed huh.) thus I thought no adaptor is available for driving it with that high speed, except for changing my Mac